# What is an SDL renderer?

Tags: c++, sdl, terminology, sdl-2

I'm starting with SDL2 and having some trouble trying to understand what an SDL_Renderer is.

What is it? What does it do? What's the difference between SDL_Renderer, SDL_Window, SDL_Surface and SDL_Texture and how they are related?

I had issues with this when trying to understand  this introductory code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main()
{
    /* Starting SDL */
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Create a Window */
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Create a Render */
    SDL_Renderer *render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (render == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Load bitmap image */
    SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("./Tutorial/res/Lesson1/hello.bmp");
    if (bmp == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Upload surface to render, and then, free the surface */
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, bmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
    if (texture == nullptr){
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Draw the render on window */
    SDL_RenderClear(render); // Fill render with color
    SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture, NULL, NULL); // Copy the texture into render
    SDL_RenderPresent(render); // Show render on window

    /* Wait 2 seconds */
    SDL_Delay(5000);

    /* Free all objects*/
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    /* Quit program */
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I was using Twinklebear tutorial (suggested on SDL Wiki) and looked also on SDL Wiki Documentation and some books. But all of them assume that I know these definitions.

Comment: `/* Wait 2 seconds */ SDL_Delay(5000);` comment mismatches with code... ;-)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

### SDL_Window

`SDL_Window` is the struct that holds all info about the Window itself: size, position, full screen, borders etc.

---

### SDL_Renderer

`SDL_Renderer` is a struct that handles all rendering. It is tied to a `SDL_Window` so it can only render within that `SDL_Window`. It also keeps track the settings related to the rendering. There are several important functions tied to the `SDL_Renderer`

- `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a);`
  This sets the color you clear the screen to ( see below )
- `SDL_RenderClear(renderer);`
  This clears the rendering target with the draw color set above
- `SDL_RenderCopy(`
  This is probably the function you'll be using the most, it's used for rendering a `SDL_Texture` and has the following parameters :

  - `SDL_Renderer*   renderer,`
    The renderer you want to use for rendering.
  - `SDL_Texture*    texture,`
    The texture you want to render.
  - `const SDL_Rect* srcrect,`
    The part of the texture you want to render, NULL if you want to render the entire texture
  - `const SDL_Rect* dstrect)`
    Where you want to render the texture in the window. If the width and height of this `SDL_Rect` is smaller or larger than the dimensions of the texture itself, the texture will be stretched according to this `SDL_Rect`
- `SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);`
  The other SDL_Render* functions draws to a hidden target. This function will take all of that and draw it in the window tied to the renderer.

---

### SDL_Textures and SDL_Surface

The `SDL_Renderer` renders `SDL_Texture`, which stores the pixel information of one element. It's the new version of `SDL_Surface` which is much the same. The difference is mostly that `SDL_Surface` is just a `struct` containing pixel information, while `SDL_Texture` is an efficient, driver-specific representation of pixel data.

You can convert an SDL_Surface* to SDL_Texture using

```
SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                                          SDL_Surface*  surface)
```

After this, the SDL_Surface should be freed using

```
SDL_FreeSurface( SDL_Surface* surface )
```

Another important difference is that `SDL_Surface` uses software rendering (via CPU) while `SDL_Texture` uses hardware rendering (via GPU).

---

### SDL_Rect

The simplest struct in SDL. It contains only four shorts. `x, y` which holds the position and `w, h` which holds width and height.

It's important to note that `0, 0` is the upper-left corner in SDL. So a higher `y`-value means lower, and the bottom-right corner will have the coordinate `x + w, y + h`

---

You can read more about SDL2 on my [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20220128092015/http://headerphile.com/).

Comment: @olevegard, great answer. Just to clarify the difference between SDL_Texture and SDL_Surface, I would emphasize that SDL_Texture renders using the GPU and SDL_Surface uses software redering, which is less efficient but lets you manipulate freely the pixel information. Also, great blog, I will surely read it :)

Comment: The top answer has some inaccuracy, SDL_Renderer can tied to surface too, not only to window, please check the link: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer

Answer (score 11):

Think of `SDL_Window` as physical pixels, and `SDL_Renderer` and a place to store settings/context.

So you create a bunch of resources, and hang them off of the renderer; and then when its ready, you tell renderer to put it all together and send the results to the window.